# Reversing cron job mail activity

Tags: cron, oracle

Hiii 
I want to check the reason behind failure of cron job mail activity without accessing server's maillog ? Is there any other way to check 'why mail wasn't send ?

Comment: Welcome to AU: what mail agent have you installed on what system, and how ? (i.e. we need "some" details on yr setup ...) Details aside, it may just be that you need to (re-)configure how your mail works, whether it is postfix or some'g else.

Comment: Thanks,but the real problem is 8 out of 10 times email was received from server but failed 2 times. And I want to find reason behind the failure without accessing 'Server's mail log'. I only have access to client's side.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any documentation shared on response code of mail server? If then, return the response code on each time your cron job try to send email. And keep that response code into DB or alternate location to monitor and identify the issue.